# Why WriteToFile method does not works in (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender?

Tags: objective-c, ios, writetofile

the following is my source code:

/*--'fileName' is an available filePath.--*/

```
NSLog(@"%@", @"v-log start");
NSMutableArray *txtArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[txtArray addObject:@"test"];
[txtArray writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", @"v-log end");
```

those code can be run perfectly if I put them in the (void)viewDidLoad

but I get 'FilesHandling[3294:c07] *** -[NSPathStore2 getFileSystemRepresentation:maxLength:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7146ad0' Exception when I put them in (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender.

Can you please tell me why ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the fileName string has been deallocated. Did you retain it?

Comment: Thank you ben, after your kindly reminder, I check my code again and use self.fileName to replace 'fileName'. then, it works :)